# make an addressable led strip shift from one pattern to the next after a set amount of time

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, led

I have a raspberry pi and an addressable led strip hooked up to it and I also have a bunch of patterns. What I want to do is basically showcase the patterns and colors that I have without having to send the commands individually. I'm a serious novice to all of this and I don't know how to tell it run one pattern for X amount of time and then go on to the next. I put the code for two of the patterns below. Any help is much appreciated, i've been scouring the internet for tutorials but everything is about arduino and I don't have access to any of that. Thanks in advance for any advice!!

import board
import neopixel
import time
pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.D18, 6)

pixels.fill((0, 230, 230))   is the first one and then i'd like it to switch to the next after about 5 seconds

import board
import neopixel
import time
pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.D18, 6)

pixels.fill((51, 0, 51))

I have searched all over the Google and not been able to find anything about what exactly I need to write.

Comment: This question is too broad for StackOverflow. You can group commands into functions so you can re-use them together. Start with learning Python, then read the documentation for the APIs you're using. Come back here if you have a more specific question.

Comment: I'm going to answer this because I think OP only needs one new construct (while loop), and doesn't even need to know about functions etc. So not too broad.

Comment: Neil, you were right. I ended up figuring it out a few hours after I posted, I knew it was gonna be something simple. Thanks a ton for taking the time to help out a new! Super excited to keep learnin

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get something to run *perpetually*. This is a service as opposed to a batch job. Normally, how you implement a service is by having a loop that just keeps running.

Note, I'm *assuming* that you are making the correct calls here to the neopixel and board api.

```
import board 
import neopixel 
import time 

pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.D18, 6)
while(True):
    pixels.fill((0, 230, 230))
    # Now, make it wait for however long you want
    time.sleep(5)
    pixels.fill((51, 0, 51))
    # Now, make it wait again
    time.sleep(5)
    # At this point, it's just going to loop back to the top again! and will
    # keep going until you kill it.
```

If you have a lot of patterns that you want to loop through, then you can put them into some iterable structure, like a list. Then, you can loop over those, with a for loop.

```
import board 
import neopixel 
import time 

pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.D18, 6)
patterns = [(0, 230, 230), (51, 0, 51), (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
while(True):
    for pattern in patterns:
        pixels.fill(pattern)
        # Now, make it wait for however long you want
        time.sleep(5)
```